# Cannot see file list in Plunker Editor

Tags: plunker

When I open Plunker, I cannot see the Project directory, or any files.  All i see is an ad for ag-Grid.  I can see the files when I open the Embedded view, but I should be able to click on a file and edit it in the Editor, right?  The tutorials (on youtube) all show the list of files in the left-hand pane, but I can't see them.

UPDATE: This is happening in Internet Explorer, Edge and Version 10.  It works properly in Version 9. In the console I noticed several files had 'Access Denied'  There is a Microsoft TechNet note about this problem.  Instead of fixing it (MS said I would have to update some registry settings) I switched to Chrome. *Mischief managed*.

Comment: I get this same issue. Anyone figure this out?